# PhpStorm file types in name specific folders

Tags: types, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, typoscript

I have some files with different names and two `.ts` and `.txt` extensions always in `somePath/**TypoScript**/anotherPaths` I want to assign to TypoScript but only if the txt is inside TypoScript folder.

like

```
Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Lib/ParseFuncRte.txt
Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/TtContent/Content.ts
```

are both TypoScript.

Could I define in PhpStorm something like this?

```
\**/TypoScript/**/*.txt
```

Comment: File type assignment (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types`) is **1)** does not allow paths in patterns -- only file names **2)** It's an IDE-wide setting (affects ALL projects) and therefore cannot be applied conditionally on per-folder basis.

Answer (score 2):

File type patterns don't support paths, and file associations are stored globally, on IDE level, so there is no way to set up file association on package/project level.
Please vote for related feature requests: [IDEA-107807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107807), [IDEA-113835](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113835)